# Detect Xamarin Forms mobile app update via gmail/playstore

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-install-apk

I have an Xamarin forms app already installed on my android device say beta 1. suppose I want to install an update for it (Beta 2) via apk from gmail, I can click on apk and it gets installed. but I want to update some info after this update.

So which method is called after the update is done, so that I can add some code in there.

Thanks

Comment: There isn't any.  When your app starts you have to check if the updates have been done; if they haven't, then do them and set some sort of flag to indicate they've been run.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by storing the version name to sqlite database. And in the main page I always check if the Android manifest's version name is same as stored version name in local sqlite db.